# Thrust is going towards the earth, but the plane is going upwards, Why?

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-simulator

Dears,
I am trying to develop a flight simulation, but I am facing a problem when the plane goes downwards towards the earth.
As shown in the picture below:
[image]

In equilibrium state before the plane pitch downwards the following parameters:

Thrust force is 1960 kgf 
Weight is 98000 kgf 
Lift is 98000 kgf 
Drag is 1960 kgf 
Angle of attack is 0 deg

The speed was 166 m/s 

When the plane pitch downwards towards the earth, The speed increases so lift coefficient increases then the lift force increases till it comes more than the weight and the plane begins to move upwards.
What I am making wrong, what are the lift coefficient or what are the forces that should take the plane downwards?

Comment: Isn't lift defined as the force pointing in the opposite direction of the weight? And the aerodynamic force, which is the force actually generated by the wing and is composed of both a lift and drag component so points upwards and backwards from the airframe? That arrow you have labelled as lift doesn't seem to  point in the proper direction for the lift or aerodynamic force. Not an expert so I may be wrong here.

Comment: All the forces only affects acceleration, the derivative of the plane's current velocity. When lift increases, it doesn't mean the plane will go up immediately, it will gradually level then start to climb. What you are seeing here is a transient moment when the plane is just starting to level not full leveled, so is still going down.

Comment: If there aren't ongoing control inputs, the aircraft will work to return to its prior equilibrium state (assuming positive stability). So if it's only a single, momentary pitch-down input, what you described will play out in oscillations that return you to level flight. If there is ongoing control input to HOLD the nose down to a given (negative) pitch, the control force will increase as speed increases, but then the nose can stay down & speed will build. All depends on what the controls are working to achieve.

Comment: And, minor note, drag will increase with increasing speed.

Comment: DKNguyen: the lift force is perpendicular to the direction of movement, it is opposite to the weight only when the plane is moving forward.

Comment: user3528438: Yes you are right but it doesn't go up immediately it takes a while till the linear velocity changed. But at last it goes upwards.

Comment: Ralph: yes the the plane return to the equilibrium state but the lift still increases in the upward direction. Yes the drag force increase but if you composite the drag force here, part of the drag force is composite upward direction which helps in the plane goes upwards. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: @Ahmed Elhamy many folks work with gliders at first.  "thrust" with gliders is force vector in the **line of flight**, a combination of gravity and the horizontal component of lift.  With a powered aircraft, descending, it is still these forces, plus whatever $thrust$ the engine is adding *in the direction of flight*.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Congratulations, you have just discovered... **Vbg!**

First, remember **vertical lift** opposes weight, and this will be the $cosine$ of your lift vector (which is correctly drawn).  As your speed increases, your plane will depart from its *line of flight* (which is descending).  With a glider, the wing is now not only supporting weight, it also has a horizontal component which *propels the aircraft forward*.  With gliders, this little trick only works until form drag eliminates the benefits of using the more efficient wing for thrust at a slightly higher speed.

But, as Peter said, the plane will stabilize at its trim speed, but look at what happens to lift when we "reduce pitch" in the Lift Equation:

Lift = Coefficient of Lift x Density x Area x Velocity$^2$.

Even though reducing pitch makes the Coefficient of Lift *smaller*, Lift increases by the **square** of the velocity, so you *get more lift by going faster*, even though the nose is pointing toward earth.

Now add thrust (from an engine) and, yes, you can climb using excess lift from your wing
(even if the nose points toward earth, or below the line of flight).

> what am I missing?

As speed increases, Lift increases, plane begins to rise, **now gravity contributes less to forward velocity**, plane slows down, Lift decreases, plane descends ...

Now you have discovered ... **static stability!**

> the plane begins to move upwards...

... from its *line of flight*.

Comment: As I can understand from your explanation is that, the plane should elevate upwards slightly but because of thrust force it will take the plane downwards. This means that my thrust force is very small, that's why it couldn't take the plane downwards. Am I right?

Comment: Make thrust zero, the plane must descend.  As it angles downwards, it does speed up, **but the Lift vector is no longer vertical**. Cosine of lift vector (vertical lift) gets smaller and smaller, even though plane speeds up, as angle of descent increases.  At a 90 degree decent (straight down) there is no vertical lift, just drag to oppose gravity.  **weight is the force that takes the plane downwards**, but thrust will help if there is no vertical lift, but not too many people do that. 

Comment: Thrust gives forward velocity, which is needed to create lift.

Comment: Thank you guys especially Robert and Peter, The problem solved. Yes you were right.

Comment: Why is this answer sitting at -3?

Comment: @sox with Monica because I dared mention "you can climb using excess lift if the thrust vector is below the line of flight".  Even with static stability, every climb (departure from linear flight in the "up" direction) starts with increase in speed from more throttle.  A staticly stable plane will seek its trim speed, a neutral plane (like many airliners) must add in a bit of pitch up or it will simply speed up.  As it turned out from much study, climbing this way is higher drag, which would limit upward acceleration.  But if I were overloaded, I would dare not raise the nose above the horizon

Comment: This phenomena of "levitation without pitchup" can be clearly observed with a simple hand glider by moving the weight back until the *tail also requires upforce*.  Now there is upward motion from excess lift (created by an increase in airspeed, such as a gust) without change in pitch.  *this is valuable, as a gust hitting a glider with **excess static stability will pitch up and stall it** more easily*.  One lesson learned with balsa free flights at the "hill".

Answer (score 3):

Watch the pitch equilibrium better.

Normally, when an airplane picks up speed in a dive, the lift coefficient drops. This will shift the balance of moments (lift and weight times their moment arms) such that the aircraft returns to its old speed (after several oscillations).

Unless you show us the full mathematical model, it is hard to say where you went astray. Calculate the contributions of every part and sum up forces and moments. Then, interpret every residual force and moment as an acceleration (by dividing forces by the mass and moments by their moment of inertia) and integrate them over a small time-step. Repeat. Trim the model with appropriate control deflections and power settings. It is much work, but rather straightforward.

Comment: That is what I actually do in my code. But the first section is important, Why the lift coefficient should be dropped. Yes it may dropped for a while due to angle of attack but when the plane nose goes to the linear velocity, the angle of attack will be zero which gives high or efficient angle of attack to increase the lift force.

Comment: @AhmedElhamy Why would the plane drop its nose if not from elevator deflection to make it pitch down? This will also trim a lower lift coefficient – there is no good reason why the lift coefficient goes up!

Comment: Why this will lower the lift coefficient, the angle of attack should be zero as the plane nose is going with the direction of movement. Is there anything that can affect the lift coefficient other than angle of attack?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're calculating all these forces in the correct axis? Weight is always straight down toward the Earth, but the other three forces rotate with the plane as shown in your diagram.

If the nose of the plane is pointed straight down, then the force of thrust points directly down and thus is added to gravity. Drag will point straight up, and lift will point horizontally.

With so much more downward than upward force, the plane will accelerate very quickly. This will increase lift of the wings (assuming they aren't ripped off) and *negative* lift on the horizontal stabilizer. So, assuming no further elevator input, the plane will naturally rotate upward and pull itself out of the dive. This is a passive safety feature inherent to the design of most (but not all, particularly military) airplanes.

Comment: "The plane will naturally rotate upward and pull itself out of the dive", not if the tail stalls from the wing pulling the plane "sideways", friend.  This is the extreme case of a "staticly stable" configuration.  The wing over powers the tail, the plane will not "pull out". It is actually easier to pull an "unstable" plane out of a dive (it "turns" easier).  In a practical sense, chopping power is a very good move to control speed in a dive to avoid Vne, as you suggest.